# R for loop skip to next iteration ifelse

Tags: r, for-loop

Suppose you have a for loop like so

```
for(n in 1:5) {
  #if(n=3) # skip 3rd iteration and go to next iteration
  cat(n)
}
```

How would one skip to the next iteration if a certain condition is met?

Comment: Instead of skipping when a condition is met, you should _not skip_ when a condition is _not met_--`for(n in 1:5){if(n!=3){cat(n)}}`

Comment: @MichaelChirico Would `for (n in c(1:2,4:5)) { cat(n) }` be a further improvement?

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms maybe, maybe not. it's harder to read, I'd say, with ~0 change in performance. but depends on context.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

```
for(n in 1:5) {
  if(n==3) next # skip 3rd iteration and go to next iteration
  cat(n)
}
```

Comment: Neat. To OP: see `?Control` for similar features

Comment: very neat answer indeed， what if  I want to do some thing like  `for(n in 1:5) {
     if(n==3) print ('3rd iteration' ) next # skip 3rd iteration and go to next iteration
     cat(n)
 }` meaning I want to print that I 'm gonna to skip 3rd iteration, cause in some cases we need to record what we skipped to keep things tractable.any thought on this?

Comment: @Jason Goal - you'll need extra brackets for the `if` statement, like this `for(n in 1:5) { if(n==3) { 
  print ('3rd iteration' ) ; next }
  # skip 3rd iteration and go to next iteration cat(n) 
}`

Comment: Thanks@ Alexey Ferapontov, now I see why the 'extra bracket ' error keep popping up at my old version.