# R: Set loop index from within the loop

Tags: r, loops

I want to set a loop to run from 1 to 10. Then from within the loop I want to change the index so to skip iterations 6 and 7, and complete the loop with iterations 8, 9 and 10.

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  print(i) 
  if (i == 5) {
    i <- 8
    print(i)
  }
}
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 5
[1] 8
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```

Clearly, `i` after my line `1 <- 8` is set by the function `for` to 6. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: `R` allows to use a variable twice in this case and corrects for unusual programming style. The looping variable remains unaffected by the change of `i` within the loop. The variable defined inside the loop is stored effectively as a separate variable.

Comment: Why not loop over only the variables you want to do something with? Or use an `if(i satisifies condition){do something} ` construct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076971/r-for-loop-skip-to-next-iteration-ifelse)

Answer (score 5):

As you're talking about skipping, the best idea is to use next on the values you wish to skip:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  if (i %in% c(6,7)) {
    next
  }
  print(i) 
}
```

Quote from `help("for")`:

> `next` halts the processing of the current iteration and advances the
>   looping index.

Another option is to restrict the ranges your looping over like this:

```
for(i in c(1:5,8:10)) {
  print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
i=1
while (i<=10) {
  print(i) 
  if (i == 5) {
    i <- 8
  }else i<-i+1
}

[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this :

```
for( i in 1:10) {
    if(i!=6 && i!=7) {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

And, another is :

```
i = 1
while(i<=10) {
  print(i) 
  if(i == 5) {
    i <- i + 3
  } else {
    i <- i+1
  }
}
```