# Plotting a matrix multiplication

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I am trying to plot a matrix multiplication as a function of time and run into a problem of not being able to include the original state into the plot (where `n = c(100,1000,50)` ).

I tried searching for a solution in other SO posts, but could only find the [next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076971/r-for-loop-skip-to-next-iteration-ifelse) function, which, I think, is not good because if I write it into the `if (time ==1){}` section, it skipps the original state just the same. Eventually, I came up with this, which does not work either:

```
n = c(100,1000,50) #original state
G = matrix(c(0.6,0.4,0,0.005,0.9,0.1,0,0,0.5),3,3) 

population = function(time = 100){
  x = seq(0,100,1)
  plot(x = seq(0,100,1),y = seq(0,1000,10), col="white", xlab = "time", ylab = "sample")
  if(time == 1){
    points(x[1],n[1], col = "red") 
    points(x[1],n[2], col = "blue")
    points(x[1],n[3], col = "black")
  }
  for(i in 1:(time-1)){
    n = G%*%n
    print(n)
    points(x[i],n[1], col = "red") 
    points(x[i],n[2], col = "blue")
    points(x[i],n[3], col = "black")

  }
  return(n)

} 

population(100)
```

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather use the function `matplot` because it's easier to really control what it actually produces. Also, the code becomes much clearer.

```
N <- matrix(NA, 3, 100)
N[, 1] <- c(100, 1000, 50)
G <- matrix(c(0.6, 0.4, 0, 0.005, 
              0.9, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.5), 3, 3) 
for (i in 2:ncol(N)) {
  N[,i] <- G %*% N[, i-1]
}
matplot(x=0:99, t(N), type = "p", pch=1,
        xlab = "time", ylab = "N")
```

[image: The result with matplot]

Comment: This is indeed very neat and short! Thank you so much!