# skipping iterations in R loops

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

ive been asked to program a game that prints "boom" each time a number is either divisible by 7, or contains 7, for seq(1:31) . so far so good:

```
num_turns=c(1:31)
for(i in seq(1,31)){
  if(i%%7==0 || "7" %in% i){
    print("boom")
  }else{
    print(i)
  }
}
```

then im asked to repeat the game for seq(1:55), but with conditions: there are 4 players, im player #3, and to only print my turns. 
these are the variables i was asked to create:

```
total_players=4
player_num=3
turns=55
```

any advise on how to code this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R for loop skip to next iteration ifelse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076971/r-for-loop-skip-to-next-iteration-ifelse)

Comment: i saw this question but didnt understand the answers given.

Answer (score 0):

```
num_turns=c(1:55)
for(i in seq(1,55)){
  if(i %% 4 == 3 &(i%%7==0 || "7" %in% i)){
    print("boom")
  }else{
     print(i)
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, first thanks for answering, secondly when i try to run the code i get this error message: Error in mod(i, 4) : could not find function "mod"

Comment: %% stands for modulus. Changed it.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the first part of the question:

```
for (i in 1:31) {
  if (i %% 7==0 || grepl("7", i)) {
    print("boom")
  } else {
    print(i)
  }
}
```

Here is a vectorized version:

```
i <- 1:31
ifelse(i %% 7==0 | grepl("7", i), "boom", i)
```

For the second part of the question:

```
total_players <- 4
player_num <- 3
turns <- 55
i <- 1:turns
allT <- ifelse(i %% 7==0 | grepl("7", i), "boom", i)
myT <- allT[seq(player_num, turns, total_players)]
```

Comment: Uses the wrong sequence.  Try `my.turns = seq(player_num, turns, total_players); 
ifelse(!my.turns%%7 | grepl(7,my.turns), "boom", my.turns)`