# Skip specific value in lapply based on a condition

Tags: r, lapply

In a `for loop`, it is possible to skip to the next iteration using `next()`. As in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32077002/3588876):

```
# skip 3rd iteration and go to next iteration
for(n in 1:5) {
  if(n==3) next 
  cat(n)
}
```

I would like to do something similar when applying my function to a list of objects. Something sort of like this:

```
l <- c(1:2, NA, 4:5)

myfun <- function(i){
                    if(is.na(i)) next
                    message(paste('test',i))
                    }

lapply(l, myfun)
```

Is there a way to skip specific value in lapply based on a condition?

Comment: how about - `lapply(na.omit(l), myfun)`?

Comment: I would filter `l` before using `lapply`. If you want to known where exception occurs, you can use the `?tryCatch` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `return` nothing or `NULL`

```
lapply(l, function(i)  if(is.na(i)) return(NULL) else message(paste('test',i)))

#test 1
#test 2
#test 4
#test 5
#[[1]]
#NULL

#[[2]]
#NULL

#[[3]]
#NULL

#[[4]]
#NULL

#[[5]]
#NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do a `for`loop

```
 for(i in seq_along(l)) if(is.na(l[[i]]))  print(NULL) else cat(paste('test', l[[i]]), "\n")
#test 1 
#test 2 
#NULL
#test 4 
#test 5
```

---

Or using `map_if`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_if(l, ~!is.na(.), ~ cat(str_c('test ', .x), '\n'), .else = ~cat(NULL))
#test 1 
#test 2 
#test 4 
#test 5 
#[[1]]
#NULL

#[[2]]
#NULL

#[[3]]
#NULL

#[[4]]
#NULL

#[[5]]
#NULL
```