# Skip iteration and return NA in nested for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, nested, iteration, skip

Given the data frame:

```
test <- structure(list(IDcount = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), year = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Otminus1 = c(-0.28, -0.28, -0.44, 
-0.27, 0.23, -0.03, -0.06, -0.04, 0, 0.02), N.1 = c(NA, -0.1, 
0.01, 0.1, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.05, -0.05), N.2 = c(NA, 
NA, -0.09, 0.11, 0.06, NA, -0.08, -0.08, -0.09, -0.09), N.3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 0.01, 0.07, NA, NA, -0.12, -0.13, -0.13), N.4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.04, NA, NA, NA, -0.05, -0.05), N.5 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.13)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    IDcount = c(1, 2), .rows = structure(list(1:5, 6:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and a results data frame:

```
results <- structure(list(IDcount = c(1, 2), N.1 = c(NA, NA), N.2 = c(NA, 
NA), N.3 = c(NA, NA), N.4 = c(NA, NA), N.5 = c(NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to perform a nested for loop like the following:

```
index <- colnames(test) %>% str_which("N.")

betas <- matrix(nrow=length(unique(test$IDcount)), ncol=2)
colnames(betas) <- c("Intercept", "beta")

for (j in colnames(test)[index]) {
  
  for (i in 1:2) {
    
    betas[i,] <- coef(lm(Otminus1~., test[test$IDcount==i, c("Otminus1", j)]))
  }
  
  betas <- data.frame(betas)
  
  results[[j]] <- betas$beta
}
```

The for loop is supposed to run the regression across each column and each ID and write the coefficients into the data frame "results".
This works, as long as each ID has one value in each column. Unfortunately, my data frame "test" is missing values in the column "N.5". The regression and loop can therefore not be performed since all values for this ID are NA.

I now would like to adapt my loop so that iterations are only performed if there is at least one non-NA value for a certain ID in the specific column.

Following this explanation [R for loop skip to next iteration ifelse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076971/r-for-loop-skip-to-next-iteration-ifelse), I tried to implement the following:

```
for (j in colnames(test)[index]) {
  
  for (i in 1:2) {
    
    if(sum(is.na(test[which(test[,1]==i),.]))==length(unique(test$year))) next
    
    betas[i,] <- coef(lm(Otminus1~., test[test$IDcount==i, c("Otminus1", j)]))
  }
  
  betas <- data.frame(betas)
  
  results[[j]] <- betas$beta
}
```

But this doesn't work.

I would like to receive a data frame "results" looking something like this:

```
IDcount  N.1    N.2   N.3   N.4    N.5
 1       0.1    0.2   0.5    0.3   NA
 2      -5,3   -0.8  -0.4   -0.1  -0.1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `colSums` to perform a check :

```
index <- colnames(test) %>% str_which("N.")

betas <- matrix(nrow=length(unique(test$IDcount)), ncol=2)
colnames(betas) <- c("Intercept", "beta")

for (j in colnames(test)[index]) {
  
  for (i in 1:2) {
    tmp <- test[test$IDcount==i, c("Otminus1", j)]
    if(any(colSums(!is.na(tmp)) == 0)) next
    betas[i,] <- coef(lm(Otminus1~., tmp))
  }
  betas <- data.frame(betas)
  results[[j]] <- betas$beta
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The loop in your code went through, but seems to stop writing the coefficients of the regression into the data frame "results" when reaching column "N.4" and "N.5". 
I've edited my question, so you can see the result I would like to achieve ;)

Comment: No actually `betas$beta` for both `N.4` and `N.5` is `NA`. See `coef(lm(Otminus1~., test[test$IDcount==1, c("Otminus1", 'N.5')]))` and `coef(lm(Otminus1~., test[test$IDcount==1, c("Otminus1", 'N.4')]))`

Comment: You're right! Thanks again for your help ;)

Comment: Is there maybe an easy way to switch out the x and the y variable and also integrate no intercept in the regression so that it states ```lm(.~Otminus1 -1, tmp)```?

Comment: Shouldn't `lm(.~Otminus1 -1, tmp)` work as it is?

Comment: Unfortunately, I receive the following error message ```Error in model.frame.default(formula = . ~ Otminus - 1, data = tmp, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : Objekt is no matrix```

Comment: It expects data to be matrix ? Try using `lm(.~Otminus1 -1, as.matrix(tmp))` then?

Comment: Really weird, now it expects it to be a data frame: ```Error in model.frame.default(formula = . ~ Otminus1 - 1, data = as.matrix(tmp),  : 'data' must be a data frame, neither array nor  matrix```

Comment: Not sure what is happening there. Maybe you can ask that as a new question?